# Perl code to delete a multi line XML node

Tags: perl

I have an xml file `test.xml`

```
<many-nested-roots>

    <foo>
      <bar>
      </bar>
    </foo>
    
    <other-random-nodes></other-random-nodes>

    <foo>
      <bar>
        <foobar>
        </foobar>
      </bar>
    </foo>
    
    <!-- multiple such blocks not in any particular order -->

</many-nested-roots>
```

I need to delete xml node `<foo><bar></bar></foo>` but not `<foo><bar><foobar></foobar></bar></foo>`.

EDIT: The node `<foo><bar></bar></foo>` occurs multiple times and randomly across a heavily nested XML.

**What I tried which doesn't work:**

`perl -ne 'print unless /^\s*<foo>\n\s*<bar>\n\s*<\bar>\n\s*<\/foo>/' test.xml`

^ This doesn't match for newline

`perl -ne 'print unless /<foo>/ ... /<\/foo>/' test.xml`

^ This deletes all the tags including `<foobar>`

`perl -ne 'print unless /<foo>.*?<bar>.*?<\/bar>.*?<\/foo>/s' test.xml`

^ I used `/s` to let `.` match for newline. Doesn't work.

Comment: That is not a valid XML file (it doesn't have a root element). No XML parser will be able to parse that file.

Comment: @zdim : Removed one-liner. Earlier impression was this would be a straightforward job with Perl.

Comment: @DaveCross Edited the xml file to accurately represent the data. Thanks.

Comment: @snackbar "_Removed one-liner_"  -- so I removed my comments referring to that

Answer (score 5):

A one-liner using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) and an XPath expression to find the nodes to delete:

```sh
perl -MXML::LibXML -E '
  my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $ARGV[0]);
  $_->unbindNode for $dom->documentElement->find("//foo/bar[count(*)=0]/..")->@*;
  print $dom->serialize' test.xml
```

(Old versions of perl need `@{$dom->...}` instead of `$dom->...->@*`)

Or using [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php) (not perl, but very handy for scripted manipulation of XML files):

```sh
 xmlstarlet ed -d '//foo/bar[count(*)=0]/..' test.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, however it's not the first occurrence. I have edited the question to reflect this. 

Also can't use any external programs apart from default, coz I'll be running in servers where I won't have access to install programs.

Comment: @snackbar Updated answer with new XPath paths to match your update. Get permission from the sysadmin or whoever to install programs needed to effectively work with the data you're expected to process. You don't drive screws with a hammer, after all, and being expected to do so is unreasonable.

Answer (score 4):

As @Shawn and @tshiono said, you should not use regex but a XML parser. Here is an example, but not a one-liner, using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) provided by [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojo::Base -strict, -signatures;

use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::File 'path';

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse(path($ARGV[0])->slurp);
$dom->find("foo bar")->each(
  sub ($el, $i) { $el->parent->remove if $el->children->size == 0 }
);
print $dom;
```

If you save it as myscript.pl you can call it with `./myscript.pl test.xml`.

Comment: I ran this solution after installing Mojo deps locally and it totally works! However I need to run the command on servers where the dependencies are light and I don't have full permission to install external packages. :( I'm still on the hunt to achieve this default perl/sed/awk programs.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try:

```
perl -0777 -pe s'#<foo>\s*<bar>\s*</bar>\s*</foo>\s*##g' test.xml
```

The `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp whole file at once to make the regex match across lines.

Please note it is not recommended to parse XML files with regex. `Perl` has several modules to handle XML files such as `XML::Simple`. As a standalone program, `XMLstarlet` will be a nice tool to manipulate XML files.

Comment: General programming languages can handle XML just fine if you're using an XML parser. It's regular expressions that shouldn't be used (Yet all too often are, sigh).

Comment: @Shawn thank you for the comment. You're right. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just not `XML::Simple`, which had been superseded by much better tools a long time ago. Its own documentation has for years advised against its use.  Some good current libraries: `XML::LibXML`, `XML::Twig`, `Mojo::DOM`.